# Images are not loading in https protocol

Tags: html, ssl, https

i have a website which as working perfectly through http, but when i have secured https protocol for that website url, then the images are not loading on site, if we make refreshing page once or twice it will displays images else page loading for long time with no images shows.

Comment: Please include the code

Comment: what is the link to your website?

Comment: If you are on https://www.yourwebsite.com do you still load resources / your images via http?

Comment: i have image path like this <img src="images/image_name.jpg"> for every page, is this problem with image pah, is there any way i can chane path for those images to work on https:// url also.

Answer (score 0):

The images on your page need to be loaded through the same protocol as the protocol present in the link.

So in conclusion if the website is loaded through https, the images need to be loaded through https also and the other way around.

Comment: No I'm not, but with that amount of information, this is the only idea I found for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue with the code or possibly a ssl error. Please Contact your server and ask them for an ssl certificate. It be something to do with your computer/browser.